# Setting an image on IKImageView not working?

Tags: cocoa, core-graphics, ikimageview

I am working with IKImageView. I have a filepath URL which I am using to add an image to my IKImageView. I have tried with 2 ways : 
**1.** `- (void)setImage: (CGImageRef)image imageProperties: (NSDictionary *)metaData;`
   
**I am passing a CGImageRef which I get from** 
 `CGImageRef image =CGImageSourceCreateImageAtIndex(CGImageSourceCreateWithURL((CFURLRef)fileURL, NULL), 0, NULL);` 
 **and for metaData :**

```
NSDictionary *image_metadata = (NSDictionary *)CGImageSourceCopyPropertiesAtIndex(imageSource,0,(CFDictionaryRef)[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                             [NSNumber numberWithBool:NO], (NSString *)kCGImageSourceShouldCache,
                             nil]) 
[preview_ImageView setImage:image imageProperties: image_metadata];
```

**2.** - (void)setImageWithURL: (NSURL *)url;

```
 [preview_ImageView setImageWithURL:fileURL];
```

I traced the logs fileURL, image_metadata, image , while they all return values.
  Also to add i have connected IKImageView to my FileOwner , added QuartzCore, Quartz and ImageIO Frameworks. My Xcode version is 4.5.2 on MacOSX 10.8 . Dont know where I am going wrong?